# match a string outside of the brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with a word `to` how to match the word `to` only when it is outside of the brackets

```
(a turn; a task (a turn of work); to turn; Tongan cause Tongan turn)

to
```

I have tried this Regex so far, unfortunately it didn't work:

```
?<!\()\bto\b(?![\w\s]*[\)])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Since regex cannot handle nested patterns, you can't use regex for this. Try a different approach. You're using the wrong tool.

Comment: @Andreas Some regex implementations can do recursion. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.recursive_expressions and the "recursion" column of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines#Language_features . The table says that Java regexs cannot do recursion.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I know this, but why are you even telling me? Question is tagged `java`, so it doesn't matter what "some" regex implementations can do.

Comment: @Andreas You wrote *"Since regex cannot handle nested patterns, you can't use regex for this"*. Your statement appears to state a generality about regexs and not be a comment about Java regexs.

Comment: @AdrianHHH It's a comment to the question, so it implicitly shares the scope of the question unless explicitly saying otherwise. If I had said *"Strings are immutable"*, I also wouldn't be claiming that strings in all programming languages are immutable. To me, it seems obvious that such comments are within the scope of the question.

Comment: You can do balanced text using Java. It's pretty easy really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside the brackets means balanced text.
The solution is to match balanced text inline with the text you want
to find *out side* the balanced text.
You do it like this:

Globally find:

```
(?s)(?:(?=\()(?:(?=.*?\((?!.*?\1)(.*\)(?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?\)(?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)[^(]*(?=\2$)|(?!to|[()]).)*?((?:(?!(?=\()(?:(?=.*?\((?!.*?\4)(.*\)(?!.*\5).*))(?=.*?\)(?!.*?\5)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\4)[^(]*(?=\5$))(?!to|[()]).)*)(to)
```

To see what you found, replace with

```
<$3$6>
```

Sample text before:

```
to (F(i(r(s)t))) ((S)(e)((c)(o))(n)d) (((((((Third))))))) hello to 
where is a to and this is also to
(F(i(r(s)t))) ((S)(e)((c)(o))(n)d) (((((((Third)))))))
((123),(456),(789))
(a turn; a task (a turn of work); to turn; Tongan cause Tongan turn) (dsaf)
This is a you to as well as this to  here ( asdf )
```

Then after replacement:

```
<to>< hello to>< 
where is a to>< and this is also to><
This is a you to>< as well as this to>  here ( asdf )
```

[Demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyuqw74yr)

Regex stringed:

```
"(?s)(?:(?=\\()(?:(?=.*?\\((?!.*?\\1)(.*\\)(?!.*\\2).*))(?=.*?\\)(?!.*?\\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\\1)[^(]*(?=\\2$)|(?!to|[()]).)*?((?:(?!(?=\\()(?:(?=.*?\\((?!.*?\\4)(.*\\)(?!.*\\5).*))(?=.*?\\)(?!.*?\\5)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\\4)[^(]*(?=\\5$))(?!to|[()]).)*)(to)"
```

Regex readable code:

```
 (?s)
 (?:
      (?= \( )
      (?:
           (?=
                .*? \(
                (?! .*? \1 )
                (                             # (1 start)
                     .* \)
                     (?! .* \2 )
                     .* 
                )                             # (1 end)
           )
           (?=
                .*? \)
                (?! .*? \2 )
                ( .* )                        # (2)
           )
           . 
      )+?
      .*? 
      (?= \1 )
      [^(]* 
      (?= \2 $ )
   |  (?! to | [()] )
      . 
 )*?
 (                             # (3 start)
      (?:
           (?!
                (?= \( )
                (?:
                     (?=
                          .*? \(
                          (?! .*? \4 )
                          (                             # (4 start)
                               .* \)
                               (?! .* \5 )
                               .* 
                          )                             # (4 end)
                     )
                     (?=
                          .*? \)
                          (?! .*? \5 )
                          ( .* )                        # (5)
                     )
                     . 
                )+?
                .*? 
                (?= \4 )
                [^(]* 
                (?= \5 $ )
           )
           (?! to | [()] )
           . 
      )*
 )                             # (3 end)
 ( to )                        # (6)
```

---

***Good Luck !***

Comment: works great! ,only one problem it does not match the word at the starting of the string example :  `to (a turn; a task (a turn of work); to turn; Tongan cause Tongan turn)

to`

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS - Changed a character, matches `to`  at beginning.